# Global Exception handing with Spring WebFlow Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Global Exception handing with Spring WebFlow Flow.

I am working in a Spring webflow project and I would like to know if anyone knows how to add sometype of global exception handing in the flow so if any of my java calls throw a example it will catch in and bring in to the same error system for the full system?

My old flow worked with out a issues:

```
<var name="member" class="xxxx" />
<decision-state id="checkIsInPending">
   <if test="flowControllerActions.isInPending(member)" then="endStateMemberPending" else="name" />
</decision-state>
```

once I added the global to it, I started to get a error.

```
<var name="member" class="xxxxx" />

    <global-transitions>
        <transition on-exception="java.lang.Exception"
                    to="SystemException" />
    </global-transitions>


    <decision-state id="checkIsInPending">
        <if test="flowControllerActions.isInPending(member)" then="endStateMemberPending" else="name" />
    </decision-state>
```

Here is my error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 40; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'decision-state'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":on-end, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":output, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":exception-handler, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":bean-import}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rearrange XML tags. You are getting this exception because your flow XML does not comply with XSD. Myabe just put global-transition in the end

Comment: I moved the global-transition  to the end of the file and it looks like its working now

Comment: The flow.xml file does have an expected sequence, which the XSD enforces if you're using an XSD-aware editor. Try putting your global-transitions at the very end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global-transitions to catch exceptions:

```
<global-transitions>
    <transition on-exception="example.MyBusinessException" to="state3"/>
</global-transitions>
```

For more details see : [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.x/reference/flow-definition.html#transition-global)

Comment: thanks Piyush but I added some more details to my issues. your code did not work